Can I take Mod Podge on the plane?
I recently bought Mod Podge in Dubai and would like to take it back with me to Germany. According to what I researched, Mod Podge is made of PVA which is generally classified as non-flammable. But I still wanted to have a second opinion of whether it would be safe to carry it in checked luggage in an airplane? The safety data sheet of the product is here.
TL;DR: can I carry this product in a flight?


For those of us not in the know,what is it? Some sort of a hair product? Wood varnish? The label we can see doesn't really say much. Is it by any chance a liquid or a gel? Or just a dry powder?

Which airline(s)?

Does the packaging include any of the pictograms shown here or anything similar? I suppose not given the information in the safety data sheet.

@TooTea I was going to ask the same question, but a quick Google reveals it's basically a special type of glossy glue for craft projects.

Here in the US, Mod Podge is cheap enough that it may be easier to toss it in Dubai and buy more in Germany. Unless, of course, it's unavailable in Germany. It's certainly cheap enough to take in a carry on bag and be willing to throw it away if they deny it at a security check point.

Mod Podge is a liquid, I would not expect to be able to carry on an 8 oz. bottle on a plane.  (And unlike some other banned liquids, I could see how it would be used to compromise a plane's operation.)

This is just a kind of glue. While this is not allowed on board, you can definitely carry this on check-in luggage. I had carried the equivalent products in check-in luggage several times, without any issue.
